# Unknow version of apache tomcat specied in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache

I have installed Apache tomcat v8 and i wanted to connect apache tomcat server in eclipse but not able to do so.[image]

Comment: Which version of *Eclipse* is this? Did Tomcat 8.0 exist when it was released?

Comment: @nitind Eclipse version is Photon Release (4.8.0)

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#Why_won.27t_the_New_Server_Runtime_dialog_recognize_my_Linux_installed_version_of_Tomcat.3F

Answer (score 0):

This error would occur if /opt/tomcat did not contain a Tomcat installation or didn't contain a valid tomcat installation, so that the new server wizard couldn't determine the tomcat version.

So check where tomcat was installed. If it was installed to /opt/tomcat then you will need to re-do the installation.

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#Why_won.27t_the_New_Server_Runtime_dialog_recognize_my_Linux_installed_version_of_Tomcat.3F